# Convert the price from Base Currency to USD at the stage of paypal payment?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, currency, conversion

I have integrated PayPal to my website and PayPal does not support Base currency INR and support if Base Currency US Dollar.

Partial Working Method:

> app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Express\Checkout.php

```
$this->_api->setAmount($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal())
            ->setCurrencyCode($this->_quote->getBaseCurrencyCode())
            ->setInvNum($this->_quote->getReservedOrderId())
            ->setReturnUrl($returnUrl)
            ->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl)
            ->setSolutionType($solutionType)
            ->setPaymentAction($this->_config->paymentAction);
```

Just replace the below code:

```
$this->_api->setAmount($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal())
            ->setCurrencyCode('USD')
            ->setInvNum($this->_quote->getReservedOrderId())
            ->setReturnUrl($returnUrl)
            ->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl)
            ->setSolutionType($solutionType)
            ->setPaymentAction($this->_config->paymentAction);
```

**this one is working but the price Rs.70  displayed like $70 at my PayPal payment page. How to solve this issue?**

How to convert the price from Base Currency to USD at PayPal payment?

Comment: Do you have usd currency in your store

Comment: No, my store running in INR, paypal not support if base currency INR, if i change US Dollar paypal working, and above error also occurred.

Comment: You need to do currency conversion to archive this.

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a lot of functionality to convert currency. It is designed as a multi-lingual and multi-currency application.

The easiest way to convert from the base currency into the current selected store currency is with the following code:

```
$amount = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($baseAmount, false, false);
```

You can also use the directory helper:

```
/* @var $helper Mage_Directory_Helper_Data */
$helper = Mage::helper('directory');

// second param = 'from', third param = 'to'
$amount = $helper->currencyConvert($amount, 'USD', 'EUR');
```

To make sure your currency exchange rates are up to date, you need to enable cron for the magento website and make sure that the schedule imports are enabled:

**Magento Admin** > **System Config** > **Currency Setup** > **Scheduled Import Settings**

To answer the specific question about Paypal, look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772976/magento-paypal-currency-error).

Answer (score -1):

As you need the complete solution goes here,

```
$from_Currency='INR';
$to_Currency='USD';
$amount = urlencode($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal());
$from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
$to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
$url = "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency";

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = explode('bld>', $rawdata);
if(count($data) < 2){
    $data[1] = '';
}
$priceinusd = explode($to_Currency, $data[1]);
$this->_api->setAmount($priceinusd)
        ->setCurrencyCode('USD')
        ->setInvNum($this->_quote->getReservedOrderId())
        ->setReturnUrl($returnUrl)
        ->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl)
        ->setSolutionType($solutionType)
        ->setPaymentAction($this->_config->paymentAction);
```

Try this

Comment: i get error like : PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).

Comment: They are saying that your order total not matching with the amount you are passing here. So you have to modify the code in the request of paypal for the payment.

Comment: could you pls help me for that

Comment: now everything okay, currency conversion is the only problem.

Comment: You can use my code for conversion

Comment: no, your currency conversion  not working,

Comment: do you have curl enabled in your server. check the other code in php file and see if the data variable contains the value of 100INR in USD

Comment: Yes my server enabled curl and could you pls explain :: check the other code in php file and see if the data variable contains the value of 100INR in USD

Comment: what is mean: check the other code in PHP file?

Comment: could you pls join :  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62956/https-magento-stackexchange-com-questions-186519-convert-the-price-from-base-cu

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62956/https-magento-stackexchange-com-questions-186519-convert-the-price-from-base-cu

Comment: -1 because you should be using default Magento functionality for currency conversion instead of a Google API.

Comment: @PhilM Please check the entire answer and if the currency is not present in store tell him how to use default magento functionality

Answer (score -2):

if you are not using the USD as a currency in your store you can use this code for conversion.

```
    $from_Currency='INR';
    $to_Currency='USD';
    $amount = urlencode('100');
    $from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
    $to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
    $url = "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency";

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = explode('bld>', $rawdata);
    if(count($data) < 2){
        $data[1] = '';
    }
    $data = explode($to_Currency, $data[1]);
```

If you are using the USD as a currency in your store then you can use.

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency('USD')->toCurrency($price);
```

Comment: where i can i apply this code

Comment: Before this $this->_api->setAmount($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal()). and on my code $amount = urlencode($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal()); and change  $this->_api->setAmount($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal()) to $this->_api->setAmount($data)

Comment: May i know what is the error is this.

Comment: this is the error : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28105993/5906850

Comment: -1 because you should be using default Magento functionality for currency conversion instead of a Google API.

Comment: @PhilM Please check the entire answer and if the currency is not present in store tell him how to use default magento functionality